# Snowflake Query in Snowflake History shows non printable characters (smiley faces)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sometimes when I look at the query history I find a bunch of smiley faces:

[image]

Any idea of why I am getting that? And better still any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add more context, where do you see this

Comment: This is usually the result of a malformed query - often the result of dynamically constructed SQL in a stored procedure or external code. Check the entire SQL statement and look for things such as unterminated strings, invalid escape sequences etc.

Comment: @Felipe In the query history, when I look at the SQL Text. I assume it is as Greg says something malformed